# Sorting and filters

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, web-services

I need a solution for sorting and filtering, the problem is , I have an e-commerce application , when ever user Search any product the request goes to hit the data base and return list of products based on price in ascending order and now I have to give choice to user to sort based on price name, quality and rating according to his wish and now the data has to sort and process in the restful services with out hitting the database again , so could anyone tell me how to implement multiple sortings and filters to perform the action and process the data within the services with out hitting database, I am using spring boot with restful web services and java 8 version

Answer (score 0):

```
**using java 8:**
**for descending order:**
list.stream().sorted(comparator.reverseorder()).collect(collectors.tolist());
**for Ascending order.**
list.stream().sorted().collect(collectors.tolist());

**for sorting based on fields:**
For ASC
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(YOURDTO::getName)

For Desc
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(YOURDTO::getName).reversed());
```